# Header location redirect after logout to remove ?q=logout

Tags: php

As it says I need to remove the  ?q=logout. First I tried this

```
if ($_GET["q"] == "logout") 
{
$user->user_logout();
header("location:".$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]); 
}
```

The second thing i tried:

```
if ($_GET["q"] == "logout") 
{ $user->user_logout();
header("location:include/redirect_home.php"); 
}
```

and in redirect_home.php

```
header("location:".$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]);
```

In both cases the page redirects to www.mypage.com/?q=logout
I need to remove the ?q=logout after $user->user_logout(); is processed

Comment: maybe there is another redirect.  put exit; after header and see

Comment: have you tried using POST instead of GET quick easy fix if you have no requirement for GET

Comment: exit; kills the page (blank) 
I need it with GET

Comment: That's interesting! The means the location header is not doing anything. (i.e. you are not redirecting back to a page with `q=` - you are doing nothing at all.) Are you making sure to send the header before any other content? I bet you are not, and I bet you have warnings turned off so you don't even know.

Comment: i tried localy on wamp server and it works with `header("location:http://".$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]);` why is localy working but on hosting dos not?

Comment: and yes ther is no content before this just loading some php files

Comment: Try to use "Location" instead of "location" (uppercase "L").

Comment: Dosent work with uppercase L , same result , but in response from GET ?q=logout i get `ï»¿` what is that ?

Comment: Seam like i was calling some files before , so i putted 
`if ($_GET['q'] == 'logout') 
{
include_once ('include/functions.php');
$user = new User();
    $user->user_logout();
 header("Location:http://".$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]);
 exit;
}` just after `session_start();` 
And now its working fine 
Thanks @Ariel

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this: `header("location:".$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]);`

You need the `http://` part before the server name.

```php
header("Location: http://{$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']}/");
```

Comment: Then you will need to see the actual headers. Install an addon in your browser that lets you see headers and see what your program is actually doing.

Comment: in respos to GET ?q=logout i get `ï»¿` . ?